# Writing a process to array all folders and subdirectories in a path

Tags: arrays, directory, scripting

I've been working on writing a process to order a directory array that branches through all folders/subdirectories from top to bottom of a fixed path, following the branching folders until the end of the current branch, then moving backwards, one folder at a time, moving down to the next folder, and repeating the process; this using a 3rd party proxy script language that is not mainstream.  So far I have totally failed at accomplishing this and feel that I have become lost being able to.  I think I need guidance at this point.  I am having serious issues with realizing how to track where I am in the traversing of the arrays.

I only have access to a function 'getDirList' that returns an array of all the folders within the provided path (e.g., getDirList $folder_array $path_of_current_folder), as well as: if...elseif.else...end, while...end, both arrays and multi-dimensional arrays (e.g., $array[$i][$subarray][1]), and math operators ($v--, $v++, =, etc.), := (to set the value of a variable), etc.

I'm needing this to go through the array in order to generate a list of file names using a 'getFileList' function.  And am hoping for guidance on how to properly construct this, as I've been dabbling at this for about 2-weeks now and I feel that I cannot think clearly on it anymore.

I've rewritten my process many times and have only gotten it to work a little one way or another.  I took a break for about a week to clear my head, however, now after a few days of attempting anew, I have only taken steps backwards.